# Simulation mismatch when shifting a +5v pulse to -12v

Tags: arduino, mosfet

I am attempting to switch a N-channel mosfet (IRF740) running on a -12v rail using an arduino which outputs a 0v/+5v pulse. The end goal is to supply a -12v/-7v pulse to the MOSFET gate.

After four days of simulating many unsuitable and complicated circuits involving comparators or countless transistors, I have finally come up with this circuit which appears to achieve my goal of a -12v/-7v pulse at RLOAD1:

[image: circuit]

This is the output of the simulation using Kicad simulator; The white line is the Arduino output, and the blue is the voltage at RLOAD1:

[image: simulation]

With the blue line indicating the voltage at RLOAD1, it appears to achieve my goal.

Following a victory cheer, I replicated this circuit on a breadboard. When testing with an oscilloscope, I am seeing a -8/-3v pulse rather than the -12/-7v pulse I expected - this will result in the mosfet being constantly saturated.

- Is there a reason for the mismatch in voltages, and how can I correct
  this?
- Is there a better overall way to achieve my end goal?
- Have I simply made an error in my configuration of VPULSE's voltages?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: How **exactly** did you connect the oscilloscope probe and its ground wire? Was the 1M resistor also present when you connected the oscilloscope?

Comment: The oscilloscope is grounded at the DC positive, and the probe is at RLOAD1. I have tested with and without the 1M resistor, with the same result.

Comment: If the scope is grounded at the 12V positive end, then you are actually observing \$V_{RLOAD}-12\$, is that right? Do the values you report account for that?

Comment: Yes, this is what I expect to be observing. I have also placed the probe at the battery negative to ensure i'm expecting the correct floor.

Answer (score 1):

- let V2 be a 74HCxxx CMOS driver or similar thus ~50 Ohm =Vol/Iol at xx mA +/- 50%
- let R2 =0
- let R1 =0

Then expect Vo(1M) = -11.4V, -7.5V. OK? Or do you want higher Vgs=ON? Like -10,-5 or .?? define ideal ?.

- add 1.6V (Vf=2V@10mA) 5mm RED LED as a LV Zener in place of R2 to level shift upwards by this amount.
- expect -9.1V,-4.1V
- adjust level shift for desired NFET Vt (threshold of conduction =xxx uA) by choice of LED Vt (Red<=1.6, White<=2.6V at low leakage current thru 1M. Or simply add another diode (1N4148 small signal diode) no need for 1A diode.

I did not simulate to verify.

Comment: This does seem like it may work, I'll simulate it to see the result. While I would like a higher Vgs=ON, I am probably constrained by the lower threshold of the MOSFET which is 2.0v and so would require the voltage to be lower than -10 when off. I'll try the diodes as suggested to shift it.

Comment: You can boost 5V to 12V with any transistor right? But 2 to 7V for Vgs should work but your complete load specs and reactance are undefined

Answer (score 0):

Your 5V output is not enough to reliably drive an IRF730 fully on. You need a logic-level MOSFET. The IRF740 is also a 400V MOSFET, perhaps you don't really need that high a voltage rating- the consequence is that it has relatively high Rds(on) of around half an ohm with 10V drive.

If you do have a MOSFET that will work well with 0V/5V Vgs, you can use a circuit like this:

[image]

D2 and D3 with the resistors protect your Arduino from a potentially large negative spike depending on what order the power supplies are applied.

To get the simulation to match reality you would need a model of the MOSFET **and** the load, because the gate requires considerable current to switch and the Miller capacitance means that the drain voltage affects the gate current during switching.

Comment: Thanks for your recommendations - though the low current supplied by the Arduino is of no concern right now as it's going to be fed through a push-pull transistor configuration which has already been tested and proven, I just require the correct voltages to give their base.

IRF740 is chosen indeed because of its specifications. Threshold is max 4.0v and at 5.0v, according to the datasheet it will pass 10amp which is more than I'll require over 50-200uS.

Comment: @berzuka Typical at 25°C is only 3A and if you happen to get a weak unit it could be just mA. The only guarantees are at 10V gate drive (and that if you give it 4V Vgs you'll get at least 0.00025A). It's a good idea to use guaranteed limits when designing, then you know it will work rather than just tinkering.